# useContext is not updating some components while it is working fine for others

Tags: reactjs, web, react-hooks

I am using Context to work with cross-component state. I have 3 levels of component, all component have access to the context using useContext but the thing is whenever the changes to the context takes place it is reflected in the middle level component but the other two is only showing the initial state. I can't think of something that can be wrong. help me out if possible.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how many `Context.Provider` you have used.

```
const Branch = ({ theme1, theme2 }) => {
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={theme1}>
      // A. value = theme1
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={theme2}>
        // B. value = theme2
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
      // C. value = theme1
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
    // D value = defaultTheme
  )
}
```

You can have different values for location A,B,C, and D. Article explaining this problem, https://javascript.plainenglish.io/react-context-is-a-global-variable-b4b049812028.

Comment: I have only used a single Provider on the top level that encapsulates all three components.

Comment: Double check your Context definition, all `useContext` has to get the same context, not from different file import. Or show all your source code.

Comment: is it happening because I am using `const CategoryCtx = useContext(CategoryContext)` in all three of the components?

Comment: this is correct, but `CategoryContext` has to be from the same import. And three components has to be under the same `CategoryContext.Provider` parent :) Otherwise you still run into the cases that i mentioned above.

Comment: yes! it's working now instead of creating a new context for all three component I just create it once in the parent and passed all it's value down as props, so that it can also be used in it's children. Thank You! @windmaomao

Comment: You are welcome, please accept the answer if you believe the answer helped, thanks.